# How to add custom font files to an ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, font-face

Everything is working fine locally, but the problem is that the font files I've added aren't showing in Solution Explorer and aren't getting built into the project when I deploy it to my web server, although everything works fine locally.

Because right-clicking on the **fonts** file in Visual Studio didn't give me any options of using **Add** for font files, I manually added them to the folder through Windows File Explorer.

Same goes for some Javascript that I added. What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot of situation:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7061S.png]

Comment: try right click fonts folder > Add > Existing item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add an existing item:

1. Right click the folder you want to add the files
2. Hover over `Add`
3. Select `Existing item`
4. Select the file(s) you would like to add.

Alternatively, if you've already done it the way you have, you need to add them to the solution file. You can do this manually (bothersome, could end up screwing it up), or, in solution explorer you will see there are icons at the top, there is one that shows all files:

[image: show all files button]

Now if you navigate to your folder in the solution explorer, you can right click this items and select `Include in project`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this button:

[image: Show all files button]

This will display files that are not properly included in project, but exists in the correct folder. Once you've clicked that, you will see grayed-out files in the solution explorer, on which you can right click and select "Include in project".

**EDIT:**

To make this easier in the future, you can copy-paste directly on a folder in the solution explorer. The files will be copied to the correct directory *and* included in the project immediately.